# Why pipe.write blocks a thread?

Tags: ruby

Here is the sample program:

```
from = File.open('test.bin', 'rb')
to = IO.popen('cat', 'w+b')
i = 0

while buff = from.read(4096)
  to.write(buff) # blocks here
  i += 1
  print "#{i}, #{buff.size} bytes read                \r"
end
```

it reads binary file (you can create it with `fallocate -l 1MB test.bin` on Linux) and pipes to `cat` command.

However, `to.write(buff)` call hangs. Here is how it looks in console:

```
[1] pry(main)> from = File.open('test.bin', 'rb')
#<File:test.bin>
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 1000000 Mar 30 13:38 test.bin
[2] pry(main)> to = IO.popen('cat', 'w+b')
#<IO:fd 14>
[3] pry(main)> i = 0
0
[4] pry(main)> 
[5] pry(main)> while buff = from.read(4096)
[5] pry(main)*   to.write(buff)  
[5] pry(main)*   i += 1  
[5] pry(main)*   print "#{i}, #{buff.size} bytes read                \r"  
[5] pry(main)* end  
33, 4096 bytes read
```

So it writes only 135168 bytes. But why?

Also, if I use different command (I need it for gpg with some parameters), amount of bytes is different (around 60 MB), but result is the same, it blocks at exactly the same point (this point is different for `cat` and `gpg`, it remains the same for each program no matter how many times you run the program).

Environment: Ubuntu Linux, ruby 2.3.4p301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it blocks is because `IO.popen` opens a pipe with both a write AND a read file handle and associated read and write buffers.

Since you're not reading at all from the read handle of the `io` object, the read buffer eventually gets full (since `cat` is constantly copying its input to its output), and once the read buffer is full the OS blocks the write side of the pipe until there is room in the read buffer again.

You've effectively created a deadlock situation.

The solution is to either keep reading from the read side, in order to prevent the read buffer from blocking, OR to not make the command output anything.

Reading from the read handle can be tricky, because it's a blocking call in itself. You would need to set up non-blocking reads, or you could just use a separate thread to do the reading instead.

The simplest solution however, is to prevent `cat` from outputting anything, and hence you will never create the deadlock situation:

```
to = IO.popen('cat > /dev/null', 'w+b')
```

This may or may not be what you are after, but it should give you some ideas on how to proceed.